# MongoDB: Failed to set up sockets during startup

Tags: mongodb

I have Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 bit machine. I have installed mongodb msi for windows with SSL support. I created all the perquisites required for environment setup. Now using command prompt I navigated to the bin directory present into the mongodb installation folder and executed the following command:

mongod.exe --dbpath "c:\data"

And I see the following response:

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongod.exe --dbpath "c:\data"
2016-05-27T17:09:43.362+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2
108 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=TestServer
2016-05-27T17:09:43.363+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/W
indows Server 2008 R2
2016-05-27T17:09:43.364+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.6
2016-05-27T17:09:43.364+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 05552b562c7
a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25
2016-05-27T17:09:43.364+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL
 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
2016-05-27T17:09:43.364+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-05-27T17:09:43.364+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-05-27T17:09:43.364+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-05-27T17:09:43.364+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ss
l
2016-05-27T17:09:43.364+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-05-27T17:09:43.365+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-05-27T17:09:43.365+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-05-27T17:09:43.365+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed
errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port
) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2016-05-27T17:09:43.366+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets
 during startup.
2016-05-27T17:09:43.366+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

Can anyone please help me to how to fix this issue.

Comment: Is something is already running on port 27017?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

run

```
netstat -a -n | find "27017"
```

and chek if port 27017 is already used

> F:\data\bin> netstat -a -n | find "27017"
>
> TCP    **0.0.0.0:27017**    0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

or run taskmgr and find and kill all mongod processes

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I ran the taskmgr and kill the mongod process and it worked for me. I now see waiting for connections on port 27017 message on the console output :)

Comment: @profesor79 I need your help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064638/how-can-i-solve-failed-to-set-up-sockets-during-startup-when-i-run-mongodb-se. Maybe you can help me